# SQL Developer - Views, Row ID & Insert

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-01446

"CID","NAME","EMAIL","LOC" are the Attributes of the two tables

> Create View TEST_V As
>
> Select * From Table1
>
> Union
>
> Select * From Table2;

---

> Insert Into TEST_ERROR (Source_Rowid, Source_Table, Filter_Id,
>   Date_Time, Action)
>
> Select ROWID, 'TEST_V', 100, sysdate,'Request Admin'
>
> From   TEST_V
>
> Where  LOC = (Select CityList From Location);

Location is another Table and has CityList defined in it, I want to match and CityList with LOC and then Add the row.

The Error I am getting is:

*SQL Error: ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
01446. 00000 -  "cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the ROWIDs of the base tables of the view do this:

```
Create View TEST_V As
Select Table1.*, rowid as row_id From Table1
Union all
Select Table2.*, rowid as row_id From Table2;
```

then:

```
Insert Into TEST_ERROR (Source_Rowid, Source_Table, Filter_Id, Date_Time, Action)
Select ROW_ID, 'TEST_V', 100, sysdate,'Request Admin'
From TEST_V
Where LOC in (Select CityList From Location);
```

Comment: I did the did the same thing you told me, but I am still getting the same error. "Select CityList From Location" is from another table do we have to use a join statement? as I would like to match LOC with all the columns of CityList.

Comment: Sill getting the same error, The code seems to be correct and the logic too but Its not working :(

Comment: Did you change `ROWID` to `ROW_ID` in the insert statement?

Comment: UNION ALL, not UNION I think.

Answer (score 0):

in this query ( loc= select citylist from location ) in this many cities are selected at once so these can't fit in loc at same time that why its giving the error 
SO try this ( loc =( select citylist from location where citylist='as name of one city in your table') )
I think it will work